# angular-route not working with nested controllers

Tags: angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, angular-routing

I have an angular page with the following structure:

```
<div ng-controller="MainCtrl">
    <div ng-controller="HeaderCtrl">
    <div ng-view>
```

The problem is, any links located within MainCtrl div and outside HeaderCtrl div work well, but the links inside HeaderCtrl, for some reason, cause a full page reload, instead of being intercepted and handled by Angular client side router.

What am I doing wrong? how do I prevent this?
Thank you.

I must add I am using html5mode.

EDIT: OK it was some crappy hiden non-angular JS changing the onclick attribute.

Answer (score 0):

You should look at the [ui-router](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router) to handle nested controllers. The basic `ng-router` handle it not gracefully and cause bugs likes yours.

`ui-router` API is very close from `ng-router` making it simple to switch to it. It will fix your bug and allow you to use nested templates / controllers inside your routes.

Comment: Nah, I changed angular-route for ui-router and still happens.

Answer (score 0):

OK it was some crappy hiden non-angular JS changing the onclick attribute.